# Extract and validate a date from a CSV value

Tags: c#, datetime

**Valid dates are :** 1-JAN-2016, 29-FEB-2016.

**Invalid dates are :** 1-JU-2016, 1/10/2016 etc.

I'm using TryParseExtract to get the date, but it's not working.

**Sample data being tested:** 20-FEB-2016

**Date output from extract:** {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}

I'm trying to make sure the csv element matches this date format.

```
            string format = "DD-MMM-YYYY";
            DateTime dateTime;

            if (fileStillValid == true)
            {
                while (currentLine < lines.Length)
                {
                    string[] current = lines[currentLine].Split(',');
                    if (!rcCodeRegex.IsMatch(current[0]))
                    {
                        fileStillValid = false;
                        invalidRedemptionCode = current[0];
                        break;
                    }
                    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(current[1], format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
                    {
                        // do something here. 
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileStillValid = false;                       
                        break;
                    }

                    currentLine++;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your format's wrong... letter case matters. Try this instead:

```
string format = "d-MMM-yyyy";
```

Comment: Why do you care if CSV matches format "d-MMM-yyyy"?  Can't you test for any valid date by using Parse() instead of ParseExact()?

Comment: It's a requirement from the client that it matches that format.